# PC Power LED stopped blinking when in sleep mode

Tags: motherboard, bios, led, front-panel

pc power led stopped blinking when in sleep mode. when pc is in normal mode, there is no problem.
Can you help me why this is happening and hos can i fix this? Thanks.

Comment: The computer is probably entering a hibernate mode, rather than sleep. You can check your power settings to see if your computer is using a sleep or hibernate setting. You could also check in the BIOS like Brady has mentioned.

Comment: Why *probably* hibernate? The OP states sleep, so it is probably sleep.

Answer (score 1):

My initial thought is that the sleep mode has been changed from **S1** mode to **S3** mode in the BIOS settings.  That causes a "deeper sleep" and lets more components shut off.  It saves energy, but the hard drive is probably off due to this change, therefore the hard drive activity light is not blinking.

Comment: Definitely this. When the computer is asleep, the hard drive turns off and the hard drive activity light stops blinking.

Comment: @Narzard: OTOH, nearly all PCs I've seen blink the _power_ light in S3 mode...

Comment: I think it just depends on the motherboard and firmware version of the BIOS.

Comment: The OP is about the power led, and not the drive leds